# Strings and Nested For Loops in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem where I want to have a nested for loop concatenate a string.  For some reason I'm not getting the correct output.  Can someone give me some advice?  This should be simple.

```
newRow = []
matrix = []
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,5):
        newRow.append(j)
    matrix.append(newRow)
print matrix

python test.py

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I want it to print...

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: That's not a string, that's not concatenating, and your indentation is off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep adding to the same `newRow`. If you want to get a clean row, you need to create an empty one on each iteration:

```
matrix = []                                      newRow = [] <- the same array
for i in range(0,3):                             matrix = []
    newRow = [] <- a new array                   for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,5):         instead of          for j in range(0,5):
        newRow.append(j)                                 newRow.append(j)
    matrix.append(newRow)                            matrix.append(newRow)
```

There are, of course, more pythonic ways of achieving this, but I'm trying to point out what the problem with the code is.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this if you want nested loop:

```
matrix = [ [  i for i in range(5)] for j in range(3)]
print matrix 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = []
for i in range(0,3):
    matrix.append(list(range(0, 5)))
```

or even:

```
matrix = [list(range(0, 5)) for i in range(0, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, its just a matter of properly scoping:

```
matrix = []
for i in range(0,3):
    newRow = []
    for j in range(0,5):
        newRow.append(j)
    matrix.append(newRow)
print matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do,

DON'T DO THIS

DON'T DO THIS

DON'T DO THIS:

```
>>> x = [range(0,5)]*3
>>> x
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> x[0][0] = 'LOL'
>>> x
[['LOL', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['LOL', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['LOL', 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

use a list comprehension.

Comment: That gives you three references to the same row.  If you set `matrix[0][0]`, you're also effectively setting `matrix[1][0]`.